# For an immutable type in a mutable reference field, use volatile and cache locally or synchronize?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

```
final class NameVolatile {
  @Nullable private volatile String name;

  void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name
  }

  void run() {
    String name = name;
    if (name != null) {
      print(name);
    }
  }
}

final class NameSynchronized {
  private final Object guard = new Object();
  @Nullable private String name;

  void setName(String name) {
    synchronized(guard) {
      this.name = name
    }
  }

  void run() {
    synchronized(guard) {
      if (name != null) {
        print(name);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above is an example of two ways to accomplish almost the same thing, but I do not have a good grasp on when to prefer one or the other.

What are the scenarios where one is more useful than the other?

I believe this question is different from [Volatile or synchronized for primitive type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779258/volatile-or-synchronized-for-primitive-type) because the question and answers there do not mention the practice of having a local cache variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volatile or synchronized for primitive type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779258/volatile-or-synchronized-for-primitive-type)

Comment: I recommend instead using an [`AtomicReference<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html)

Comment: Wouldn't that have the same downside as a volatile without the local cache? It could be set in between the null check and the print statement.

Comment: In the print statement you would use [`this.name.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#get--) in order to get a local cache.

Comment: in your example, there's no difference what to use, they work the same way in a low level code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use volatile and cache locally or synchronize?

I think you are mistaken about what the `volatile` keyword does.  With all modern OS processors, there is a local per-processor memory cache.  The `volatile` keyword doesn't enable the local cacheing -- you get that "for free" as part of modern computer hardware.  This cacheing is an important part of multi-threaded program performance increases.

The `volatile` keyword ensures that when you read the field, a read memory-barrier is crossed ensuring that all updated central memory blocks are updated in the processor cache.  A write to a `volatile` field means that a write memory-barrier is crossed ensuring that local cache updates are written to central memory.  This behavior is *exactly the same* as the memory barriers that you cross in a `synchronized` block.  When you enter a `synchronized` block, a read memory-barrier is crossed and when you leave a write is crossed.

The biggest difference between `synchronized` and `volatile` is that you pay for locking with `synchronized`.  `synchronized` is *necessary* when there are more than a single operation happening at the same time and you need to wrap the operations in a mutex lock.  If you are just trying to keep your `name` field properly updated with main memory then `volatile` is the way to go.

Another option is an `AtomicReference` which wraps a `private volatile Object` field and provides atomic methods like `compareAndSet(...)`.  Even if you are not using the special methods, many programmers feel that it is a good way to encapsulate the fields you need to be memory synced.

Lastly, both `volatile` and `synchronized` also provide "happens-before" guarantees which control instruction reordering which is important to ensure proper order of operations in your program.

In terms of your code, you should never do something like:

```
synchronized(guard) {
   if (name != null) {
       print(name);
   }
}
```

You don't want to do expensive IO inside of a `synchronized` block.  It should something like:

```
// grab a copy of the name so we can do the print outside of the sync block
String nameCopy;
synchronized(guard) {
   nameCopy = name;
}
if (nameCopy != null) {
   print(nameCopy);
}
```

With `volatile`, you want to do one `volatile` field lookup so something like the following is recommended:

```
void run() {
   // only do one access to the expensive `volatile` field
   String nameCopy = name;
   if (nameCopy != null) {
      print(nameCopy);
   }
}
```

Lastly, from the comments, `volatile` is significantly more expensive than a normal operation (which can use cached memory) but `volatile` is significantly *less* expensive than a `synchronized` block which has to test and update the lock status on the way in and way out of the block *and* cross the memory barriers that affect all cached memory.  My back of the envelope testing shows that demonstrates this performance difference.

Comment: Cool, yeah, I understand the basics you pointed out; I was just interested in the two styles I listed above. That's a really good point about expensive operations in the block; I was just using that as an example, but thanks for the reminder. Your second snippet is my second solution, it looks like. So, I think (barring the `print` being inside the block) my solutions are pretty equivalent, then, right?

Comment: Equivalent in terms of memory synchronization and instruction ordering.  Not at all equivalent in terms of performance @EricCochran.

Comment: The performance difference is just because of the I/O implied in print, though, right? Any other performance differences?

Comment: No, the locking is much more expensive than just a memory barrier @EricCochran.  `synchronized` is more expensive than `volatile`.  Synchronized has to test and update the lock's status in addition to updating the cached memory.  My quick tests show that volatile is 10x faster although YMMV.